# How to download a file only if its modified in android activity

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that needs to download a script from the web
but the file is too large and I want to download only if it's modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if **Support** you can use The `If-Modified-Since` HTTP Header

> The “If-Modified-Since” HTTP header is sent from an agent
>   (browser/bot) to the web server in order to know if the requested page
>   has been changed since its last visit. The server responds with a 200
>   code (Ok) if the page has been modified or with a 304 code (Not
>   modified) if the page has not been modified.

Refer [The If-Modified-Since HTTP Header](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/10/19/the-if-modified-since-http-header/), where given an *easy way to check if a web server supports the if-modified-since HTTP header*